# Druid SQL: get substring issue

Tags: sql, druid

There is the table column which holds the comma-separated values, e.g:

```
abc321,rd512,spwewr
```

I need to extract the substring which starts from the user-defined pattern.
Example:

```
Input Pattern |  Expected result
abc              abc321
r                rd512
spwe             spwewr
b                NULL
```

Following fails in Druid SQL:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('abc321,rd512,spwewr', POSITION('r' IN 'abc321,rd512,spwewr'), 2)
```

This is the known Druid bug:
" Substring operator converter does not handle non-constant literals correctly":

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CALCITE-2226

I think the way to go is to use REGEXP_EXTRACT() or REGEXP_LIKE()
but I cannot figure out the specific syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
select regexp_extract('abc321,rd512,spwewr', 'rd[^,]+', 0)
```